# simpleError - trailing garbage -Rstudio

Tags: r, json, parsing, rstudio

im using Rstudio to get data from esp32

i got this error :

> simpleError: parse error: trailing garbage
> 9c ac fb 3f 9c ac fb 3f 6c 36

My code is like this :

> str(req$bodyRaw)

> print("\n")

> data <- jsonlite::parse_json(req$bodyRaw)

> print(data)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is `parse_json` requires a "string with literal json or connection object to read from" not a raw vector. From the information provided I have no idea what the structure of `req` is, but often there is another property such as `body` that will be the character representation of the body. Alternatively, `jsonlite::parse_json(rawToChar(req$bodyRaw))`

Comment: i tried this, i got a new error : <simpleError: lexical error: invalid char in json text. Note that its worked for me a week ago , i dont know why its crashing now